# Why spring boot blocking api faster then project reactor?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

guys!

I want to compare project reactor's performance with standart blocking API

I created for that purpose 2 simple applications. Both application have same model, controller, service and repository.

After that I prepared simple JMeter test, with 400 threads and loop count is 40. I expected, that standart blocking api to die with NoSpaceLeftException or be much slower than reactive application. But it turned out the opposite. Blocking API's read from database is much faster: 3 seconds (blocking API) VS 9 seconds (Reactor). In db are only 10 records. With inserts similar situation.

Blocking Api results
[image: Blocking API results]

Project reactor results
[image: Project reactor]

Could someone explain to me where am i wrong?

I want to know why reactor so slow? Maybe my test case is not good for this purpose. Maybe my expects about Project Reactor advantages is not correct. Tell me please.

Comment: Reactive isn't about speed but about smarter use of resources (unless you start doing things in parallel that you before weren't doing in parallel). Reactive also makes only sense if you can be reactive from front to back. If you are using JDBC or JPA in there it still is blocking as those technologies are blocking. So in short with this little information this question will be impossible to answer.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I use jpa repository for blocking api and R2DBC (with reactive postgres driver) for Reactor

Comment: This seems like a very common question we all had in our brains about reactive but never dared to ask on stackoverflow, hence my damn nickname.. joking aside, the reactive way will be less likely to be thread starved than your usual mvc app (unless you explicitly block). Another thing about reactive is that r2dbc is still very nascent and may not have enough driver magic to optimize and batch requests as opposed to any other jdbc that has been around for more that 20 years. All in all, test it on some limited resource node, it will outperform mvc counterpart in stability and throughput.